# Novice level - do DataURLs automatically save to a specific location?

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, data-url

I am a complete novice, doing some work on a HTML5 drag and drop game. I am looking at coding tutorials which will save an image of the game when the user presses a button. The canvas image is saved as a DataURL. I kind of understand what this means. But my questions are: where does the image save to (as you don't seem to need to specify a location) & will an image saved to that location always have a unique URL (i.e. images saved from different games wont overwrite).

Answer (score 0):

The Data Url is just a Base64 encoded string which represents an image. I'm not sure about your exact implementation, but you almost always would have to save that string at some persistent location. Try the [Local Storage](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CFUQFjAB&url=http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_webstorage.asp&ei=fI8jUKPbHcuxrAf8vYG4Ag&usg=AFQjCNEuM20wo8w5KZczd08LTptJk3-Wjg) for instance if you want to save the image on the user's machine and not on a server.

Otherwise, you can always POST the Base64 encoded string via Ajax to your own server and save it in a file or database.